# how to add three condition at Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use three condtions in my `if` statement. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var num_one; var num_two; var num_three;
        $("#control").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        $('#col-1 li').click(function(){  num_one = true;  getState();});
        $('#col-2 li').click(function(){  num_two = true; getState();});
        $('#col-3 li').click(function(){  num_three = true; getState();});

        function getState(){
            if ((num_one == true) & (num_two == true) & (num_three == true)) {
                $("#control").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        }

        /*$('#col-1 li').click(function(){$("#control").removeAttr("disabled");*/
    });

    /**$("#enableBtn").click(function() {
        $("#clearBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
    });**/
</script>
```

It was working when I used just two conditions:  `if ((num_one == true) & (num_two == true))` but when I add a third condition it does not work. How can I add three conditions together in an if statement?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the double ampersand `&&`, not the single `&` (which is the [Bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) operator, not something you are looking for).

Also, you don't need to write `x == true`. Just writing `x` is enough:

```
if (num_one && num_two && num_three) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `&` (bitwise AND) with `&&` (logical AND). Also, because the type of the variables you're checking is boolean, you don't need the equality check.

```
if (num_one && num_two && num_three) {
```

[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/eyogoj/edit)

Comment: it works on `if (num_one && num_two ) { ` and `if (num_one && num_three ) {` but didn't work on `if (num_one && num_two && num_three) {`

Answer (score 1):

The and operator is `&&` not `&`. Change that and it should work.

Comment: col-3 retrieve data as sub list based on the col-1 and col-3 selected from table.So all your comment code are work fine in normal case.I added  `$('#col-3 li').live("click",function(){  num_three = true; getState();});` it work now.